# PY exe file is not working, what could be the problem?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, exe

i have a code that connects to my BLE device, get some info and then exports it in CSV.
It works fine (I get a csv updated with the data from ble device) with no errors but after i try to make an exe file out of it i get the following reply (in cmd).

Could someone help me please figure out what the issue is and how i can fix it?

```
c:\IDE\output\bleeeeeak>bleeeeeak.exe --debug=all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bleeeeeak.py", line 48, in <module>
  File "asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
  File "asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
  File "bleeeeeak.py", line 39, in main
  File "bleak\__init__.py", line 433, in __aenter__
  File "bleak\__init__.py", line 471, in connect
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 244, in connect
bleak.exc.BleakDeviceNotFoundError: Device with address C4:BD:00:6B:11:25 was not found.
[12636] Failed to execute script 'bleeeeeak' due to unhandled exception!
```

The device is on but the exe file doesn't see it :(.

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import logging
from csv import writer
import sys
import os

ADDRESS = "C4:BD:00:6B:11:25"
UUID = "00002a63-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
from bleak import BleakClient
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
output_numbers1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column1'])
FILE_PATH=Path(r"C:\Users\maimo\Desktop\UnrealProjects\MyProject3\Saved\power.csv")

if not FILE_PATH.exists():
    with open(FILE_PATH, 'w', newline='') as f:
        pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column1']).to_csv(f)
        f.close()

def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    global output_numbers1
    output_numbers = list(data)
    output_numbers_df=pd.DataFrame({'Column1':output_numbers[2]}, index=[0])
    output_numbers1=pd.concat([output_numbers1,output_numbers_df], ignore_index = True)


    with open(r"C:\Users\maimo\Desktop\UnrealProjects\MyProject3\Saved\power.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:
       output_numbers1.tail(1).to_csv(f, header=False)
       f.close()

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        await client.start_notify(UUID, notification_handler)
        await asyncio.sleep(120.0)
        await client.stop_notify(UUID)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.run(main(ADDRESS))
```

Comment: Part of complying with the "minimal" part of the [mre] spec is to isolate the narrowest possible reproducer. Are you really asserting that you can't cause this problem if you _don't_ convert your Python script to an executable? Can you describe how you determined that in enough detail to convince someone else?

Comment: (...it's common to have problems that only happen when packaged as an executable, but it's not common for them to be something like a `DeviceNotFoundError` -- more often you get an `ImportError` or similar, unless there's exceptionally bad error handling that's converting _all_ errors into the `DeviceNotFoundError` type).